# ASP.Net Validation for a textbox - must have minimum of 1 number but want to allow special characters & letters

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to figure out the ASP.Net validation sequence that requires a user to input at least 1 number in the text box.  I also want allow the entry of multiple numbers, characters, and any special character.  Currently, I have the following validation entry:

```
ValidationExpression="(?!^[0-9]*$)(?!^[a-zA-Z]*$)^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,20})$"
```

Right now, it passes if the user inputs 1 number and 1 letter but fires if they put in a special character at all.  Thanks for any help you can provide, it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but something along these lines should fulfill your requirements:

```
.*?\d.*?
```

This says allow any character sequence of 0 or more characters, require at least a single digit, and then allow any character sequence of 0 or more characters.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfect, I guess I was looking too far into it with my validation statement.